# Highlight current link on navigation bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, magento

Need help to highlight current category on navigation bar. How can I achieve this? I would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Example please. But I am sure magento sets a corresponding class for this already, so yes it sounds like a job for CSS.

Comment: probably be able to find out what that class is by simply viewing source

Comment: Would be helpful to have a more complete example. Do you use some magento template and try to override it? Maybe a color is already set elsewhere. You could try to override this by adding `!important` but imho this would be a last resort. If I could see the concrete page it would be much easier to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, I took a quick look on this. What I saw is that there seems to be no CSS class marking an active menu item (I think we are talking about "Home, Offers, Shop" etc, correct?) It's all plain `<li>` - so no way to distinguish these items using CSS. The first step would be to make sure the corresponding template sets a class for the currently selected item, the rest should be easy. But I don't know much about magento, so I can't help you with this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover{background-color: yellow}
```

This CSS will do it for ya.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you but it is not a hover, it would be an active I believe. I need the currently selected category/link to be highlighted.

Comment: I think it's not about  :hover or :active in this case. As I understand, the OP wants to hightlight the currently selected menu item, and not implementing a mouseover or such.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the page id of the link:
Example:

```
<a href="link_to_id"<?php if ($page_id == $link_to_id) { echo ' class="active"'; } ?>>Link</a>
```

css:

```
a.active {
font-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code of your navigation bar or link of the site you're working on

Comment: li:active a { font-color: red; }

Comment: The dynamic link already have a li class="active". You just need to add that to your css file.

Add: li:active a { font-color: red; } to your style sheet and see if it works.

Comment: I will create an answer so you can see my actual code to see if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

your 0 level menu CSS is confliction with the 1 level menu CSS
try to change in the `#nav ul li a:active{}`

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelEugeneYuen

This is my `top.phtml` file, I added

```
<li <?php if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() === $this->getUrl('Offers')):?>class="active"<?php endif;?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts')?>">Offers</a></li>
```

but I don't know if it is correctly placed

```
<?php

/**

 * Top menu for store

 *

 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation

 */

?>

<?php

/**

 * $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml() supports optional arguments:

 * int Level number for list item class to start from

 * string Extra class of outermost list items

 * string If specified wraps children list in div with this class

 */

?>

<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>

<?php if($_menu): ?>

<script>

        $j(document).ready(function(){

                $j('#nav').mobileMenu();

        });

    </script>

<div class="nav-container">

    <ul id="nav">

    <li <?php if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() === $this->getUrl('Offers')):?>class="active"<?php endif;?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts')?>">Offers</a></li>

        <?php echo $_menu ?>

    </ul>

</div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Also, i have added the CSS code you gave me to the Style.css in the 0 level

```
/* 0 Level */
    #nav li { 
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 17px 10px 0;
    }
    ul#nav{padding-left:0px }
    #nav a { font-size:18px!important;
    color: #666666 !important;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'futura_lt_btlight'; !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
    li:active a { font-color: red; }
     }
     .subcategories {
      padding-left: 0px !important;
      margin-right: 0px !important;
    }
    #mc-embedded-subscribe {
      float: left;
      width: 11px;
      background: url(https://www.blubond.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/cross.png) no-repeat !important;
      height: 11px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      text-indent: 9999px;
      border: 0px !important;
      margin-top: 7px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    #nav > li:nth-child(3) {
    background: url("../images/main_menu_dd_arw.png") no-repeat 100% 15px;  
    margin-right: 16px;
    }
    .post-entry center {
      font-family: 'futura_lt_btlight';
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }
    .page-template-blog-excerpt-php .post {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .page-template-blog-excerpt-php .post-entry {
      font-family: 'futura_lt_btlight';
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 24px !important;
    }
    .page-template-blog-excerpt-php .post-entry p {
      margin-bottom: 0px;   
    }
    .page-template-blog-excerpt-php .post-data {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
     .nav-collapse a {
    text-align: left;
    }
    .rdiregdrop
    {
        background: url("../images/top_dd_arw-3.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        display: block;
        float:right;
        height: 5px;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 11px;
        width:9px;
    }
    #nav li.over a,
    #nav a:hover { color:#9f9f9f;}
    .rdishopdd{display: block;float:right;height:5px;width:9px;display:none; margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;}
    .rdishopdd:hover{background: url("../images/main_menu_dd_arw.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); display: block;float:right;height:5px;width:9px;display:block;margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;}
```

Comment: Try this:

<li<?php if (Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() == $this->getUrl('Offers')){ echo ' class="active"'; } ?>><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('Offers')?>">Offers</a></li>

Comment: And add: li:active a { font-color: red; } to css

Comment: Check this out: http://madproject.com/programming/magento-1-6-menu-link-active-state/

Comment: This one even better: http://snipplr.com/view/54749/magento-active-states-in-top-menu/