# Hide Shopping Cart on Top Menu When it is empty

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.8

Is there a way to hide the Shopping Cart on Top Menu when it's empty? I believe it is on Links.php file but I don't know what code to add. Also, "Links.php" is a Core file, I am thinking on creating a new module on Local for it. Would it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hide the shopping cart side bar when it is empty:**

```
1. Open: app/design/frontend/default/<your template>/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml

2. Go to line 32 Look for

<div class="box base-mini mini-cart">

3. Add these lines right before that opening div tag

<?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
<?php if ($_cartQty >0): ?>

4.Add this line to the bottom of the file
```

> **The shopping cart will only show if user adds items to their shopping cart.**
>
> Or use these plugin... it's a free plugin for hiding when it is
>   empty..
>   [Xogenics Hide Cart for Magneto](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/xogenics/extension/8217/xogenics_hidecart)

**For hiding in header menu** use this

> Remove My Cart and Checkout links from the header menu.The code for
>   these links is located in the `checkout.xml` file:

```
In Magento, on your ecommerce site may be you do not want to show MyCart or Checkout links.Follow the steps below to remove the link.

1. Copy the file checkout.xml from app/design/frontend/base/default/layout to app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout or app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout

2. Edit the checkout.xml copied to the app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout folder or app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout folder

3. Look for the following Code snippet
<reference name="top.links">
<block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
<action method="addCartLink"></action>
<action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
</block>
</reference>

4. Comment the following Lines

4.1 Comment the following Line to Remove My Cart Link from header
<!--<action method="addCartLink"></action>-->

4.2 Comment the following Line to Remove Checkout Link from header
<!--<action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>-->

5. Refresh the Magento Cache and Website Page to see the changes
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have added this code on sidebar.phtml already but to hide it on sidebar, and it worked but I want to hide the Cart on the top when it is empty. Thanks.

Comment: I have done that in the past. What I want is to hide the Top Menu's Shopping Cart, not the sidebar one.

Comment: Thank you very much. When an user adds a product, will it show again? Also, could you help me out with this issue also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720701/highlight-current-link-on-navigation-bar? I haven't been able to find a solution so far.

Comment: You asked to hide when it is empty only...?

Comment: Yes, only when it is empty. When an user adds an item to cart I want it to show again.

Comment: Then you don't want to display cart when user adds also means don't add these lines `<action method="addCartLink"></action>`

Comment: I have checked the files and they are already commented out and cart is still showing. Something is wrong.

Comment: Then comment the block fully `<!-- <block></block> -->`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".top-car").hide(); 
 });
```

First check if there's quantity in the cart ofcourse with something like:

```
$qty = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount()
```

Hope this helps you